# SSH forwarding from my laptop to a VM located on a remote server

Tags: ssh, forwarding

I have a remote server that hosts a VM that is running a web service on port 8000.

I want to be able to access the web service from a web browser on my laptop knowing that:

1. From my laptop, I can reach the remote server by SSH
2. From the server, I can connect to the VM using SSH
3. The web service is not directly accessible from the server.
4. Laptop keys and server keys are different.

If the web service was running directly on the server, I would do the following:

```
ssh -L 8000:localhost:8000 user@server
```

Which forwards anything I do on localhost:8000 to the remote service through SSH.
How to do something similar for the VM's case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do SSH tunnels via multiple hops. I am not sure I understand your 4th point. My guess is that what you mean is that there is a SSH private key placed on the server which is allowed by public key on the VM.

If that is *not* the case, you can quite simply jump to it:

```
ssh -J server.ip -L 8000:localhost:8000 vm.ip
```

If it is the case, you need to do something like

```
ssh -t user@server -L 8000:localhost:8000 ssh -t user@vm -L 8000:localhost:8000
```

So basically you just chain SSH commands and you can chain multiple commands, as long as you keep track of the tunneling.